# Outlook Automation - Multiple Mailboxes?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am creating an Outlook automation, where i have to manage several mailboxes.

I'd like to send mails using different mailboxes. The logged on user has the required rights to all those mailboxes. I have created profiles, where every given mailbox is the default mail box. So how can i switch those profiles and/or mailboxes using interop? Preferly by not shutting down Outlook every time i "switch".

Regards

Comment: May be of interest: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30280906/set-profile.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figured out, it does not work that simple.
Using .Logon() will enable you to select a profile, but to switch to another profile you have to shutdown Outlook completly!